# Appfabric Cache Miss Count

Tags: c#, .net, appfabric

Whenever I run the command Get-CacheStatistics **CacheName** command, it always shows a miss count that is approximately 90% of the request count, however I see that I get the object succesfully retrieved from the Cache. Any thoughts, please?

Answer (score 5):

From this [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/velocity/thread/c1a2ed3c-078b-4290-8fe4-241576339826/):

> Also, I should note that in the current release you also get a cache
>   miss on a Put() call when the object does not exist. I believe that
>   internally, the cache cluster checks to see if the item exists before
>   adding or replacing it with the Put() call. If it does not exist, the
>   miss count is incremented. So even if you just populate 10000 new
>   items to the cache, you will have a miss count of 10000 too.